# Best way to profile/optimize a website on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm currently trying to optimize my website, which is run on the Google App Engine. It's not an easy task, because I'm not using any powerful tool.

Does anyone have experience in optimizing Python code for this purpose?
Have you find a good Python profiler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found [Gprof2Dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) extremely useful. The output of the profiling modules I've tried as pretty unintuitive to interpret.

Gprof2Dot turns the cProfile output into a pretty looking graph, with the slowest chain(?) highlighted, and a bit of information on each function (function name, percentage of time spend on this function, and number of calls).

[An example graph (1429x1896px)](http://jrfonseca.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/gprof2dot.png)

I've not done much with the App Engine, but when profiling non-webapp scripts, I tend to profile the script that runs all the unittests, which may not be very accurate to real-world situations

One (better?) method would be to have a script that does a fake WSGI request, then profile that.

WSGI is really simple protocol, it's basically a function that takes two arguments, one with request info and the second with a callback function (which is used for setting headers, among other things). Perhaps something like the following (which is possible-working pseudo code)...

```
class IndexHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """Your site"""
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("hi")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
        ('.*', IndexHandler),
    ], debug=True)

    # Start fake-request/profiling bit
    urls = [
        "/",
        "/blog/view/hello",
        "/admin/post/edit/hello",
        "/makeanerror404",
        "/makeanerror500"
    ]

    def fake_wsgi_callback(response, headers):
        """Prints heads to stdout"""
        print("\n".join(["%s: %s" % (n, v) for n, v in headers]))
        print("\n")

    for request_url in urls:
        html = application({
        'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
        'PATH_INFO': request_url},
        fake_wsgi_callback
        )
        print html
```

Actually, the App Engine documentation explains a better way of profiling your application:

From http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/commontasks.html#profiling:

> To profile your application's performance, first rename your application's `main()` function to `real_main()`. Then, add a new main function to your application, named `profile_main()` such as the one below:
>
> ```
> def profile_main():
>     # This is the main function for profiling 
>     # We've renamed our original main() above to real_main()
>     import cProfile, pstats
>     prof = cProfile.Profile()
>     prof = prof.runctx("real_main()", globals(), locals())
>     print "<pre>"
>     stats = pstats.Stats(prof)
>     stats.sort_stats("time")  # Or cumulative
>     stats.print_stats(80)  # 80 = how many to print
>     # The rest is optional.
>     # stats.print_callees()
>     # stats.print_callers()
>     print "</pre>"
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> To enable the profiling with your application, set `main = profile_main`. To run your application as normal, simply set `main = real_main`.

Answer (score 8):

[App Engine Mini Profiler](https://github.com/kamens/gae_mini_profiler) is a new, drop-in app engine performance tool that gives both API call perf information (via Appstats) and standard profiling data for all function calls (via cProfiler)

https://github.com/kamens/gae_mini_profiler

Answer (score 3):

For profiling the API calls, Guido van Rossum released a library called Appstats that will record and display a lot of good stuff about your app.

You can get the library here: https://sites.google.com/site/appengineappstats/

I wrote an article about it on my blog (with some screenshots): http://blog.dantup.com/2010/01/profiling-google-app-engine-with-appstats

[Appstats http://blog.dantup.com/pi/appstats_4_thumb.png](http://blog.dantup.com/2010/01/profiling-google-app-engine-with-appstats)

Comment: Update: this is now part of the GAE SDK:
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/02/app-engine-sdk-131-including-major.html

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html

Answer (score 1):

The python site listed 3 profilers to choose from: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html