# Very high latency of python app engine app

Tags: python, google-app-engine

On both the dev server and after deployment, my app is showing very high latecy even for the lease CPU intensive request. On the dev server, a simple app that parses a JSON file could take upto 30 seconds and on appspot it's also slow with avg latency of around 800-1200ms. This same app when running in PHP responds in a couple seconds.

I'm using a template engine (jinja2) but I know that's not the cause because I've tested without it.

I'm left wondering If I want to keep wasting valueble time trying to optimize things and figuring out what's going on, or just going to a VPS like Linode and using PHP. The only thing holding me is the virtually unlimited memcache that app engine offers, and features like taskqueue, I like the platform overall.

Is there a tool that I can analyse my code and tell me what's causing the latency or something? Please give me some recommendations.

**cProfile trace after fixing issues found by appstats (was doing ~16s CPU, now much better):**

```
    204343 function calls (195607 primitive calls) in 0.726 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 782 to 80 due to restriction <80>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     8875    0.090    0.000    0.160    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\decoder.py:96(py_scanstring)
    11557    0.051    0.000    0.051    0.000 {built-in method match}
   717/63    0.050    0.000    0.244    0.004 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\decoder.py:180(JSONObject)
       59    0.039    0.001    0.039    0.001 {imp.find_module}
    26173    0.027    0.000    0.027    0.000 {isinstance}
     3315    0.023    0.000    0.023    0.000 {built-in method sub}
   5535/3    0.020    0.000    0.244    0.081 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\scanner.py:32(_scan_once)
     3281    0.020    0.000    0.046    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\encoder.py:45(py_encode_basestring_ascii)
        1    0.017    0.017    0.017    0.017 {compile}
     8084    0.015    0.000    0.063    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\encoder.py:389(_iterencode_dict)
     1816    0.014    0.000    0.022    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\nodes.py:163(iter_child_nodes)
  902/216    0.013    0.000    0.020    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\formatting.py:44(_format_value)
    580/2    0.013    0.000    0.053    0.026 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\visitor.py:34(visit)
        4    0.012    0.003    0.039    0.010 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\recording.py:578(get_call_stack)
     8487    0.012    0.000    0.079    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\encoder.py:334(_iterencode_list)
    20976    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
       21    0.011    0.001    0.041    0.002 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py:1256(find_module)
        1    0.010    0.010    0.016    0.016 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\environment.py:68(load_extensions)
        1    0.009    0.009    0.611    0.611 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\webapp2.py:523(dispatch)
      512    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 {repr}
    10759    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 {built-in method groups}
     8525    0.008    0.000    0.088    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\encoder.py:468(_iterencode)
      154    0.008    0.000    0.101    0.001 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\encoder.py:192(encode)
      203    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\lexer.py:227(__new__)
      7/3    0.007    0.001    0.060    0.020 {imp.load_module}
    11015    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {built-in method end}
        1    0.007    0.007    0.025    0.025 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\processForm.py:106(build_cities)
        1    0.007    0.007    0.054    0.054 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\recording.py:21(<module>)
    42/26    0.007    0.000    0.009    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\recording.py:944(synchronized_wrapper)
      285    0.006    0.000    0.025    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\lexer.py:548(tokeniter)
     2372    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {built-in method search}
3995/3983    0.005    0.000    0.006    0.000 {getattr}
8917/8916    0.005    0.000    0.130    0.000 {method 'join' of 'unicode' objects}
      685    0.004    0.000    0.011    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\_markupsafe\_native.py:14(escape)
     4731    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {method 'setdefault' of 'dict' objects}
      695    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\environment.py:367(getattr)
     3201    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\nodes.py:147(iter_fields)
   225/55    0.004    0.000    0.240    0.004 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\decoder.py:272(JSONArray)
        1    0.004    0.004    0.028    0.028 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\datamodel_pb.py:20(<module>)
        1    0.004    0.004    0.004    0.004 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\processForm.py:58(cleanArray)
      154    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\encoder.py:222(iterencode)
       63    0.003    0.000    0.027    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\recording.py:606(get_frame_summary)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.029    0.029 templates\my_template.html:60(loop)
      447    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\processForm.py:90(calc_distance)
     2668    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'replace' of 'unicode' objects}
     1558    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {hasattr}
      657    0.003    0.000    0.007    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\datamodel_pb.py:234(ByteSize)
     1830    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\net\proto\ProtocolBuffer.py:372(putVarInt32)
     1986    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'append' of 'array.array' objects}
      296    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 {sorted}
     1958    0.002    0.000    0.006    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\net\proto\ProtocolBuffer.py:255(lengthString)
      202    0.002    0.000    0.031    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\lexer.py:503(wrap)
        1    0.002    0.002    0.002    0.002 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\processForm.py:21(buildCraigslistUrls)
      578    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\net\proto\ProtocolBuffer.py:453(putPrefixedString)
     1958    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\net\proto\ProtocolBuffer.py:241(lengthVarInt32)
      114    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\nodes.py:126(__init__)
      937    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x1E1CED38}
   545/38    0.002    0.000    0.008    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\nodes.py:183(find_all)
     78/6    0.002    0.000    0.082    0.014 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py:649(Decorate)
      720    0.002    0.000    0.005    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\_markupsafe\__init__.py:67(__new__)
       80    0.002    0.000    0.008    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\datamodel_pb.py:414(ByteSize)
       60    0.002    0.000    0.126    0.002 templates\my_template.html:5(root)
   302/39    0.002    0.000    0.010    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\visitor.py:41(generic_visit)
      586    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 C:\Python26\lib\re.py:229(_compile)
       30    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py:1192(quote)
      575    0.002    0.000    0.006    0.000 C:\Python26\lib\re.py:139(search)
       40    0.002    0.000    0.012    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\datamodel_pb.py:442(OutputUnchecked)
      7/1    0.002    0.000    0.053    0.053 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\parser.py:844(subparse)
      353    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
      843    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
      268    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\lexer.py:237(test)
       13    0.001    0.000    0.013    0.001 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\compiler.py:1212(visit_Output)
     2055    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\net\proto\ProtocolBuffer.py:244(lengthVarInt64)
      241    0.001    0.000    0.006    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\appstats\datamodel_pb.py:254(OutputUnchecked)
      580    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\visitor.py:26(get_visitor)
      578    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'fromstring' of 'array.array' objects}
      449    0.001    0.000    0.006    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\processForm.py:83(validField)
    116/1    0.001    0.000    0.005    0.005 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\visitor.py:58(generic_visit)
     5112    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {len}
      202    0.001    0.000    0.033    0.000 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\apps\myapp\jinja2\lexer.py:336(next)
```

Comment: Where's the code? And the appstats traces? How can we debug your app without knowing anything about it?

Comment: That's not appstats, that's cprofile. And you still haven't shown us your code.

Comment: I see appstats at http://localhost:8083/_ah/stats/ but there doesn't seem to be a raw log that I can copy and paste, does it write somewhere? Also, I don't think it's a good idea for me to post my whole code here.

Comment: You need to take a screenshot and post that. And I'm not asking for all your code - just whatever's relevant to the problems you're experiencing, such as the handler in question. If you've already reduced latency to 500ms, though, there might not be much more to save.

Comment: Yea, I think most of the issue is resolved now. I'll just try to optimize the rest of the code gradually as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at those articles:

- [Easy Performance Profiling with Appstats](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/03/easy-performance-profiling-with.html)
- [How do I profile my app's performance?](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/commontasks.html#profiling)
- [Best way to profile/optimize a website on google's appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679670/best-way-to-profile-optimize-a-website-on-googles-appengine)
- [Performance profiling on Google App Engine](http://henritersteeg.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/performance-profiling-on-google-app-engine/)

> To profile your application's performance, first rename your application's main() function to real_main(). Then, add a new main function to your application, named profile_main()such as the one below:

```
def profile_main():
    # This is the main function for profiling
    # We've renamed our original main() above to real_main()
    import cProfile, pstats
    prof = cProfile.Profile()
    prof = prof.runctx("real_main()", globals(), locals())
    print "<pre>"
    stats = pstats.Stats(prof)
    stats.sort_stats("time")  # Or cumulative
    stats.print_stats(80)  # 80 = how many to print
    # The rest is optional.
    # stats.print_callees()
    # stats.print_callers()
    print "</pre>"
```

Comment: Appstats revealed that I was calling urlfetch in a forloop, resulting in a total of 53 calls. This reduced CPU time from 16s to 0.5s and latency has been reduced a lot but still not what I would consider normal. In any case this is a HUGE improvement, almost acceptable. Thank you!

Comment: Was the "same app" in PHP making 53 calls to external URLs?