# Getting AppTrace for Google App Engine working with Python 2.7 on OSX 10.8.2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

For the life of me I cannot get AppTrace to work on my Google App Engine Development server (Python 2.7 on OSX 10.8.2), mainly because of this:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/apptrace/guppy/sets/setsc.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyLong_AsScaledDouble
Referenced from: /apptrace/guppy/sets/setsc.so
Expected in: flat namespace in /apptrace/guppy/sets/setsc.so
```

This is similar to the following question, except the question is asking for the best way to profile/monitor on GAE, and the accepted answer doesn't solve the ImportError issue:
[Memory profiling/monitoring (python) on Google AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202475/memory-profiling-monitoring-python-on-google-appengine)

I also came across this information from Guppy's tracker but it still did not solve the issue:
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3047282&group_id=105577&atid=641821

When I get the 0.1.9 release directly from the trunk this is my output:

```
pip install https://guppy-pe.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/guppy-pe/trunk/guppy
Downloading/unpacking https://guppy-pe.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/guppy-pe/trunk/guppy
  Downloading guppy
  Checking out https://guppy-pe.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/guppy-pe/trunk/guppy to /var/folders/w7/k0q671gx6hb03_rl_tmcnkq80000gn/T/pip-JA8fuK-build
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from https://guppy-pe.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/guppy-pe/trunk/guppy

Cleaning up...
```

This outputs much less than what the Guppy tracker states. However, if I run python -c 'import guppy; import guppy.sets' I still get the same ImportError as before.

I'm far from a python or even an OSX expert, so any advice on what may be configured incorrectly or may be pointed to the wrong location would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! Basically when I installed Guppy using these directions:
http://code.google.com/p/apptrace/wiki/UsingApptrace

My OSX 10.8 was not building with GCC 4.2. I had to update homebrew to build with GCC 4.2:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
```

I was able to find the answer from this post:
https://superuser.com/questions/400179/gcc-on-os-x-lion-with-xcode-4-3-1