# Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 161 MB after servicing 8 requests total

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In this how to avoid exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 mb with 161 mb, and how to use taskqueue.add() for this code.thanks in advance. 
if you have any doubts i am ready to tell you.
     class ExportHandler(BaseHandler):

```
    def get(self):
        tables = []
        app_models = [m for m in dir(models.app) if not m.startswith("__")]
        admin_models = [m for m in dir(models.admin) if not m.startswith("__")]
        total = app_models+admin_models
        for mname in total:
            if mname not in REMOVE:
                label = title(mname)
                tables.append({'value':mname, 'label':label})
        fromdate = None
        todate = None
        if "fromdate" in self.request.GET:
            fdate = self.request.GET['fromdate']
            try:
                fromdate = datetime.strptime(fdate, "%m/%d/%Y")
            except Exception as e:
                pass
        if "todate" in self.request.GET:
            tdate = self.request.GET['todate']
            try:
                todate = datetime.strptime(tdate, "%m/%d/%Y")
                todate = todate+timedelta(days=1)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
        if fromdate is not None and todate is not None:
            table = self.request.GET['table']
            model_class = get_class(table, app_models, admin_models)

            model_name = model_class.__name__
            columns = model_class.properties().keys()
            query = model_class.gql("where created_date >= :1 and created_date <= :2", fromdate, todate)
            if 'date_time' in columns:
                query = model_class.gql("where date_time >= :1 and date_time <= :2", fromdate, todate)
records = [i for i in query.run()]
            if bool(records):
                fmt = "%m/%d/%Y"
                filename = "%s_%s_%s" %(model_name, fromdate.strftime(fmt), todate.strftime(fmt))
                csvfile = self.response
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
                writer.writerow(records[0].json().keys())
                for rec in records:
                   writer.writerow(rec.json().values())

                 self.response.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename=%s.csv' % filename
                return self.response
            else:
                self.session.add_flash("No records found", key='error')                                      
        self.render_response("/admin/exportcsv/index.html", tables=tables)  

    def post(self):
        print self.request.POST
        self.render_response("/admin/exportcsv/index.html")
```

Comment: try, call gc.collect at the end of the get method. It won't clear memory used for this request, but it could clear memory from the previous request. Secondly look at using a memory profile GAE Mini profiler - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742104/profiling-memory-usage-on-app-engine

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to increase 10min http request using taskqueue.add() in google appengine Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646936/how-to-increase-10min-http-request-using-taskqueue-add-in-google-appengine-pyt)