# how to increase 10min http request using taskqueue.add() in google appengine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My http request is showing deadline error like your soft memory 120mb out of 12 requests . here i want to increase http request time 10min with taskqueue.add() method.thanks in advance.

```
class ExportHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        tables = []
        app_models = [m for m in dir(models.app) if not m.startswith("__")]
        admin_models = [m for m in dir(models.admin) if not m.startswith("__")]
        total = app_models+admin_models
        for mname in total:
            if mname not in REMOVE:
                label = title(mname)
                tables.append({'value':mname, 'label':label})
        fromdate = None
        todate = None
        if "fromdate" in self.request.GET:
            fdate = self.request.GET['fromdate']
            try:
                fromdate = datetime.strptime(fdate, "%m/%d/%Y")
            except Exception as e:
                pass
        if "todate" in self.request.GET:
            tdate = self.request.GET['todate']
            try:
                todate = datetime.strptime(tdate, "%m/%d/%Y")
                todate = todate+timedelta(days=1)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
        if fromdate is not None and todate is not None:
            table = self.request.GET['table']
            model_class = get_class(table, app_models, admin_models)

            model_name = model_class.__name__
            columns = model_class.properties().keys()
            query = model_class.gql("where created_date >= :1 and created_date <= :2", fromdate, todate)
            if 'date_time' in columns:
                query = model_class.gql("where date_time >= :1 and date_time <= :2", fromdate, todate)
 records = [i for i in query.run()]
            if bool(records):
                fmt = "%m/%d/%Y"
                filename = "%s_%s_%s" %(model_name, fromdate.strftime(fmt), todate.strftime(fmt))
                csvfile = self.response


                writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
                writer.writerow(records[0].json().keys())

                for rec in records:

                    writer.writerow(rec.json().values())

                self.response.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename=%s.csv' % filename
                return self.response
            else:
                self.session.add_flash("No records found", key='error')                                      
        self.render_response("/admin/exportcsv/index.html", tables=tables)  

    def post(self):
        print self.request.POST
        self.render_response("/admin/exportcsv/index.html")
```

Comment: Timeout limits cannot be bypassed. Use a compute instance instead. If that's even your problem, difficult to tell.

Comment: To much code her, reduce it down to the bare minimum, What have you done to pinpoint where the time is consumed.

Comment: @TimHoffman What about running task queue in Appengine Backend/Module ?

Comment: It's really not clear from your question what you where asking.  Is this run as a task currently or a front facing request.  It looks like you wanted to increase http requests time, but I couldn't any urlrequests being performed.  You could certainly run this in a task but remember it will run asynchronously and you don't have control over when it starts, so then you have to work out how you will deliver the csv file.  Either by email, or store it in the datastore and email a link so that it can be retrieved etc...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're hitting the "Exceeded soft private memory limit with X MB after servicing Y requests total" error rather than a DeadlineExceededError. If that's the case, [What is the “soft private memory limit” in GAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331592/what-is-the-soft-private-memory-limit-in-gae) has some pointers.

[Scaling your instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class) can bump your memory limit up to 1 GB and should resolve this.